# How to set up MegaRAID email alerts under Linux?

Tags: linux, raid

I have Ubuntu 10.04 and MegaRAID controller. The only tool I have is the notorious MegaCli. I need to be emailed when some disk has failed in the RAID array. How to set that up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
STATUS=`MegaCli -AdpAllInfo -aALL -NoLog|egrep '^  (Degraded|Failed)'|grep -v ' 0'`;

if [ "x$STATUS" != "x" ]; then
  echo -e "Subject: RAID WARNING @ `hostname`\n\n$STATUS"|/usr/sbin/sendmail your@email.com
fi
```

and add it to your crontab: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

You also need valid sendmail program on your system, simplest config via ssmtp will be enough thou.

Comment: Nice. Do you recommend anything else to grep for, besides degraded/failed disk count?

Comment: Like warnings from log. How to get them?

Comment: Also, there seems to be a slight problem with the echo command. I get subjectless email with a body of "-e Subject: RAID WARNING @ myhostname"

Comment: what provides your /usr/sbin/sendmail command?

Comment: Postfix. I got it working properly by removing "-e".

Comment: that is weird as coreutils' echo have -e option which enables interpretation of `\n` and other escape characters: `$ echo -e "\n\n\n"` will give 4 empty lines but `$ echo "\n\n\n"` will give `"\n\n\n"` string as output. Maybe your shell has different version of echo, should have used `/bin/bash` hashbang, fixing now...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the MegaRAID Storage Manager [from LSI](http://www.lsi.com/channel/ChannelDownloads/), and it can be setup to email you on RAID events (amongst other things, like SNMP).

There's no speicifc Ubuntu version of it, but LSI provides a [knowledge base article](http://kb.lsi.com/KnowledgebaseArticle16108.aspx) that explains how to get the "Linux" version working; hopfully it'll work for you, or at least get you going.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Nagios plugin check_raid speaks megacli. You could use it standalone to write your own script. Like all Nagios plugins, it gives you an exit code of 1 if it thinks something is wrong. A cron entry like

```
sh -c "check_raid > /tmp/raid_status || cat /tmp/raid_status"
```

should give you a very basic solution.